# QueryLoader PreLoading Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, preloader

I'm using `http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader/`to preload my pages. Now, it works fine with my home page, but when I put the code on any other page, the loader just stops at 90% and it won't load... I'm using the code provided in the zip file on the site. What's the problem? I added the script which initiates the plugin

```
QueryLoader.selectorPreload = "body";
QueryLoader.init();
```

In the php file and included it in my pages... Like I said, works good on my home page, but fails on any other. Why?

Code 1:

```
var QueryLoader = {

overlay: "",
loadBar: "",
preloader: "",
items: new Array(),
doneStatus: 0,
doneNow: 0,
selectorPreload: "body",
ieLoadFixTime: 2000,
ieTimeout: "",

init: function()
{
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE (\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?:b\d*)?)/) == "MSIE 6.0,6.0")
{
return false;
}
if (QueryLoader.selectorPreload == "body")
{
QueryLoader.spawnLoader();
QueryLoader.getImages(QueryLoader.selectorPreload);
QueryLoader.createPreloading();
}
else
{
$(document).ready(function()
{
QueryLoader.spawnLoader();
QueryLoader.getImages(QueryLoader.selectorPreload);
QueryLoader.createPreloading();
});
}
QueryLoader.ieTimeout = setTimeout("QueryLoader.ieLoadFix()", QueryLoader.ieLoadFixTime);
},

ieLoadFix: function()
{
var ie = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE (\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?:b\d*)?)/);
if (ie[0].match("MSIE"))
{
while ((100 / QueryLoader.doneStatus) * QueryLoader.doneNow < 100)
{
QueryLoader.imgCallback();
}
}
},

imgCallback: function()
{
QueryLoader.doneNow ++;
QueryLoader.animateLoader();
},

getImages: function(selector)
{
var everything = $(selector).find("*:not(script)").each(function()
{
var url = "";

if ($(this).css("background-image") != "none")
{
var url = $(this).css("background-image");
}
else if (typeof($(this).prop("src")) != "undefined" && $(this).prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == "img")
{
var url = $(this).prop("src");
}

url = url.replace("url(\"", "");
url = url.replace("url(", "");
url = url.replace("\")", "");
url = url.replace(")", "");

if (url.length > 0)
{
QueryLoader.items.push(url);
}
});
},

createPreloading: function()
{
QueryLoader.preloader = $("<DIV></DIV>").appendTo(QueryLoader.selectorPreload);
$(QueryLoader.preloader).css({
height: "0px",
width: "0px",
overflow:"hidden"
});

var length = QueryLoader.items.length; 
QueryLoader.doneStatus = length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
var imgLoad = $("<IMG></IMG>");
$(imgLoad).prop("src", QueryLoader.items[i]);
$(imgLoad).unbind("load");
$(imgLoad).bind("load", function()
{
QueryLoader.imgCallback();
});
$(imgLoad).appendTo($(QueryLoader.preloader));
}
},

spawnLoader: function()
{
if (QueryLoader.selectorPreload == "body")
{
var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();
var position = "fixed";
}
else
{
var height = $(QueryLoader.selectorPreload).outerHeight();
var width = $(QueryLoader.selectorPreload).outerWidth();
var position = "absolute";
}
var left = $(QueryLoader.selectorPreload).offset()['left'];
var top = $(QueryLoader.selectorPreload).offset()['top'];

QueryLoader.overlay = $("<DIV></DIV>").appendTo($(QueryLoader.selectorPreload));
$(QueryLoader.overlay).addClass("LoadCont");
$(QueryLoader.overlay).css({
position: position,
top: top,
left: left,
width: width + "px",
height: height + "px"
});

QueryLoader.loadBar = $("<DIV></DIV>").appendTo($(QueryLoader.overlay));
$(QueryLoader.loadBar).addClass("Loading");

$(QueryLoader.loadBar).css({
position: "relative",
top: "90%",
width: "0%"
});
},

animateLoader: function()
{
var perc = (100 / QueryLoader.doneStatus) * QueryLoader.doneNow;
if (perc > 99)
{
$(QueryLoader.loadBar).stop().animate({
width: perc + "%"
}, 500, "linear", function()
{ 
QueryLoader.doneLoad();
});
}
else
{
$(QueryLoader.loadBar).stop().animate({
width: perc + "%"
}, 500, "linear", function() { });
}
},

doneLoad: function()
{
clearTimeout(QueryLoader.ieTimeout);

if (QueryLoader.selectorPreload == "body")
{
var height = $(window).height();
}
else
{
var height = $(QueryLoader.selectorPreload).outerHeight();
}

//The end animation, adjust to your likings
$(QueryLoader.loadBar).animate({
height: height + "px",
top: 0
}, 500, "linear", function()
{
$(QueryLoader.overlay).fadeOut(888);
$(QueryLoader.preloader).remove();
});
}
}
```

Code 2:

```
<SCRIPT>
QueryLoader.selectorPreload = "body";
QueryLoader.init();
</SCRIPT>
```

CSS:

```
.LoadCont
{
    Z-INDEX: 9999 !important;
    BACKGROUND: #000000;
}
.Loading
{
    HEIGHT: 1px;
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #626262;
}
```

The page is: `http://www.okultopedija.com/Ulaz?otvori=Razno`

Comment: Check the `console` for errors. Can not help you without going through your code..

Comment: @RayonDabre Nothing suspicious in the console... Everything is the same just a different page...

Comment: Can you share some code which is causing problem ?